# Why does the dropdown close as a value is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).val();
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".field-row").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".field-row").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-select .bs-ok-default::after {
  width: 0.3em;
  height: 0.6em;
  border-width: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(0.5rem);
}

.btn.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Our Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Upload Employee Details_files\style5.css">

<!-- Font Awesome JS -->
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Popper.JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />

<div class="field-rows" name="criteria_type" id="criteria_type" style="display: flex;">
  <label class="form-label">Select Criteria</label>
  <select class="form-dropdown field form-control" name="criteria" id="criteria" style="width: 230px;" required="">
    <option value="">Select Criteria</option>
    <option value="quarterly">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="half_yearly">Monthly</option>
    <option value="yearly">Annually</option>
  </select>
</div>

  <div class="quarterly field-row" name="quarter criteria_type" id="quarterly criteria_type" style="display: none;">
          <label class="form-label" style="margin-top: 15px;">Select Quarter</label>
          <!-- <div class="month dropdown-check-list field btn-group" style="display: flex; justify-content: right; margin-left: 200px; margin-top: -42px" id="kpi_type_month"> -->
            <!-- <div id="list3" class="block" tabindex="1" style="margin-right: 10px;"> -->
              <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100 " style="margin-left: 140px; margin-top: -30px; position: absolute" >
    <div id="list2" class="col-md-6" > <select id="list2_items" multiple data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow mb-5 rounded" class="selectpicker" title="Select Quarter" style="box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 10px rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5);" >
                <option  name="quarter" value="1" id="Q1">Apr - Jun (Quarter 1)</option>
                <option  name="quarter" value="2" id="Q2">Jul - Sep (Quarter 2)</option>
                <option  name="quarter" value="3" id="Q3">Oct - Dec (Quarter 3)</option>
                <option  name="quarter" value="4" id="Q4">Jan - Mar (Quarter 4)</option>

            </select> </div>
</div>

      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100 " style="display: inline block; margin-left: 400px; margin-top: -30px; position: absolute;">
    <div id="list6" class="col-md-6"> <select id="list6_items" multiple data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow-sm " class="selectpicker " title="Select Year" >
                <option name="quarter_year" value="2021">2021-22</option>

            </select> </div>
</div>
          </div>

        <div class="half_yearly field-row" name="month criteria_type" id="monthly criteria_type" style="display: none;">
          <label class="form-label" style="margin-top: 15px;">Select Month</label>
          <!-- <div class="month dropdown-check-list field btn-group" style="display: flex; justify-content: right; margin-left: 200px; margin-top: -42px" id="kpi_type_month"> -->
            <!-- <div id="list3" class="block" tabindex="1" style="margin-right: 10px;"> -->
              <div  class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100 " style="margin-left: 140px; margin-top: -30px; position: absolute" placeholder="Select Month">
    <div id="list3" class="col-md-6" > <select id="list3_items" data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow mb-5 rounded" class="selectpicker" style="box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 10px rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5);" >
                <option>Select Month</option>
                <option name="month" value="1" id="6-months">First 6 months</option>
                <option name="month" value="2" id="year">Last 6 months</option>

            </select> </div>
</div>

      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100 " style="display: inline block; margin-left: 400px; margin-top: -30px; position: absolute;">
    <div id="list7" class="col-md-6"> <select id="list7_items" multiple data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow-sm " class="selectpicker " title="Select Year" >
                <option name="month_year" value="2021">2021-22</option>

            </select> </div>
</div>
          </div>




<div class="yearly field-row" name="year criteria_type" id="yearly criteria_type" style="display: none;">
          <label class="form-label" style="margin-top: 15px;">Select Month</label>
          <!-- <div class="month dropdown-check-list field btn-group" style="display: flex; justify-content: right; margin-left: 200px; margin-top: -42px" id="kpi_type_month"> -->
            <!-- <div id="list3" class="block" tabindex="1" style="margin-right: 10px;"> -->
              <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100 " style="margin-left: 140px; margin-top: -30px; position: absolute">
    <div id="list4" class="col-md-6" > <select id="list4_items" multiple data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow mb-5 rounded" title="Select Year" class="selectpicker" style="box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 10px rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5);" >
                <option name="year" value="2021" id="2021-2022">2021-22</option>


            </select> </div>
</div>
          </div>
```

So I have these 7 dropdowns, that show after the value is selected from the Select Criteria dropdown, but when an option is selected in any other dropdown the dropdown hides altogether and we need to refresh the page to run it again, as you can run and see in the snippet, please if someone could help me with where am I going wrong, why is this problem happening?
Thank you

Comment: There's some error in console...

Comment: How do I check that>

Comment: You're hiding all fields if there isn't a value attribute on a selected option yet none of your select options have value attributes. Try this line instead: `var optionValue = $(this).val();`

Comment: The errors are coming from `<script></script>` in the snippets script area

Comment: Thankyou, but not working

Comment: No, even after changing that the problem persists

Comment: @user16396247. I have added the snippet with a solution. Can you check the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".criteria-dd")
    .change(function () {
      $(this)
        .find("option:selected")
        .each(function () {
          var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
          if (optionValue) {
            $(".field-row")
              .not("." + optionValue)
              .hide();
            $("." + optionValue).show();
          } else {
            $(".field-row").hide();
          }
        });
    })
    .change();
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-select .bs-ok-default::after {
    width: 0.3em;
    height: 0.6em;
    border-width: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(0.5rem);
}

.btn.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    outline: none !important;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Our Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Upload Employee Details_files\style5.css">

<!-- Font Awesome JS -->
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Popper.JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
<div
  class="field-rows"
  name="criteria_type"
  id="criteria_type"
  style="display: flex"
>
  <label class="form-label">Select Criteria</label>
  <select
    class="form-dropdown criteria-dd field form-control"
    name="criteria"
    id="criteria"
    style="width: 230px"
    required=""
  >
    <option value="">Select Criteria</option>
    <option value="quarterly">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="half_yearly">Monthly</option>
    <option value="yearly">Annually</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div
  class="quarterly field-row"
  name="quarter criteria_type"
  id="quarterly criteria_type"
  style="display: none"
>
  <label class="form-label" style="margin-top: 15px">Select Quarter</label>
  <div
    class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100"
    style="margin-left: 140px; margin-top: -30px; position: absolute"
  >
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select
        multiple
        data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow mb-5 rounded"
        class="selectpicker"
        title="Select Quarter"
        style="
          box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01),
            0px 0px 10px rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5);
        "
      >
        <option>Apr - Jun (Quarter 1)</option>
        <option>Jul - Sep (Quarter 2)</option>
        <option>Oct - Dec (Quarter 3)</option>
        <option>Jan - Mar (Quarter 4)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div
    class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100"
    style="
      display: inline block;
      margin-left: 400px;
      margin-top: -30px;
      position: absolute;
    "
  >
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select
        multiple
        data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow-sm "
        class="selectpicker"
        title="Select Year"
      >
        <option>2021-22</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div
  class="half_yearly field-row"
  name="month criteria_type"
  id="monthly criteria_type"
  style="display: none"
>
  <label class="form-label" style="margin-top: 15px">Select Month</label>
  <div
    class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100"
    style="margin-left: 140px; margin-top: -30px; position: absolute"
    placeholder="Select Month"
  >
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select
        data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow mb-5 rounded"
        class="selectpicker"
        style="
          box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01),
            0px 0px 10px rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5);
        "
      >
        <option>Select Month</option>
        <option>First 6 months</option>
        <option>Last 6 months</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div
    class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100"
    style="
      display: inline block;
      margin-left: 400px;
      margin-top: -30px;
      position: absolute;
    "
  >
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select
        multiple
        data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow-sm "
        class="selectpicker"
        title="Select Year"
      >
        <option>2021-22</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div
  class="yearly field-row"
  name="year criteria_type"
  id="yearly criteria_type"
  style="display: none"
>
  <label class="form-label" style="margin-top: 15px">Select Month</label>
  <div
    class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100"
    style="margin-left: 140px; margin-top: -30px; position: absolute"
  >
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select
        multiple
        data-style="bg-white px-4 py-3 shadow mb-5 rounded"
        title="Select Year"
        class="selectpicker"
        style="
          box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01),
            0px 0px 10px rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5);
        "
      >
        <option>2021-22</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have added the event handler for `select`, that was the issue. You should to be specific about the first select.

Comment: I did, Thank you

Comment: I mean upvote, the arrow to the top. That will award me another 10 points